# what's the easiest way to change the style of multiple forms on an application?

Tags: c#, .net, css, forms

Other than creating a custom button, and a custom textbox, and a custom label, etc, and then using those controls across all the forms of the application, and then changing the default colors and fonts of those controls as needed, is there an easy way to implement this kind of css-like functionality on an existing application that contains several forms?

By the way, I know that I could just programatically open each *.Designer.cs file and then search/replace instances of "System.Windows.Forms.[Control]" with "My.Namespace.My[Control]", but I'm not sure how that would work in cases where the code sets the controls' fonts and colors and similar properties. Would it then just be a matter of making sure that the custom controls override all the relevant getter methods?

Comment: Without buying a 3rd party library, there isn't an easy way to 'skin' an app.AFAIK. Have a look at DevExpress's offering. Found this free one[abandoned] (but no idea what it's like to use): http://sourceforge.net/projects/guiss/

Comment: if you were working with WPF, you could work with styles, and then apply on each form, but about winforms, i dont know.

Comment: I think that telerik also offers some custom forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Forms does not provide any kind of skinning.

An easy workaround could be to write some kind of extension method on the `Form` class:

```
public static void ApplySkin(this Form form, Skin skin)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in form.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)ctrl;
            textBox.BackColor = skin.BackColor;
            textBox.ForeColor = skin.ForeColor;
            textBox.Font = skin.Font;
            ...
        }
        else if (ctrl is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)ctrl;
            comboBox.BackColor = skin.BackColor;
            comboBox.ForeColor = skin.ForeColor;
            comboBox.Font = skin.Font;
            ...
        }
        else if (ctrl is ...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About the Designer.cs files - you should probably avoid changing their code at all. They are used by the designer and are seperated for a reason.

If you do want to change stuff, in the Form CTOR, after calling InitializeComponent(), simply call your own function with whatever changes you would like (changing attribute values such as colors, delegates etc...)

If you want several forms to have the same style (or functionality), just put this method in a different class and have all the forms use the same method by sending themselves as parameters.

Now ofcourse the method won't know which controls are on which forms so you can use Controls.Find (one of Form methods) to locate controls by name. Just make sure that the controls in your form are named correctly using the same conventions (for example, all list boxes will be named listBoxX where X is the number...).